# Err max clients reached Redis/Sidekiq/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, sidekiq

**I have been stuck on this issue for the past 3 days and unsure where to look now.**

I have a simple Sidekiq implementation into my rails app.

I am working on: Rails 4.2.0, Sidekiq 4.1.2, Redis 3.0.6

The production app is running live with heroku, and I have 1 worker dyno and 1 web dyno.

The issue is this, and I am unsure on how to approach it or what I did to make it do this.

When I run the redis-cli on heroku I can see the clients that I have running. At most I have 2 or 3 clients running at any given time. I can easily kill the clients with

`CLIENT KILL TYPE normal`

So that's all fine and dandy. The part when things get a little tricky is when I fire up my server locally, and I am working in development. All of a sudden my redic-cli shows that I have 19 clients running. This will result in me logging

`Err max clients reached`

My assumption is that somehow locally I am directing sidekiq to work off the redis production url. I have to admit what I know about Redis and Sidekiq is limited, but I do have a basic understanding of how it should be working.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sidekiq -c 3` to limit your concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a configuration error. Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question hopefully this will help them not overlook something like I did.

This issue was happening only when I was firing up my local server, so I knew it had something to do with me locally. I noticed that on my production redis:cli I was seeing clients that had my local IP in the ADDR column.

This led me to believe that my local machine was pushing clients to my production Redis server. Looking at my logs when I fired up my Procfile I saw the Redis url there so that only confirmed it.

Finally after searching through my code, I discovered that I had actually added the url into my .env, so when I fired up my server it was using that production Redis url. So I changed it to the appropriate IP address for local development on my .env file `redis://127.0.0.1:6379` and everything is now working as normal.